# Converting pandas PrettyDict to dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["a", "x", "g", "y", "q", "n"],
              'col2': ["b", "f", "s", "p", "t", "c"],
              'col3': [1, 10, 1, 1, 10, 2]}
)

>
    col1  col2  col3 
0    a     b     1
1    b     f     10
2    g     s     1
3    y     p     1
4    q     t     10
5    1     0     2
```

I grouped it based on col3:

```
grp = df.groupby(["col3"])
groups = grp.groups
```

But the result is an object with `pandas.io.formats.printing.PrettyDict` type. Is there any way that I can convert it to a normal dictionary?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: a dictionary with col3 unqiue values as keys and corresponding cells in col1 and col2 as values

Answer (score 2):

In your code `groups` is a dictionary with `col3` unique values as keys and indices of selected rows in values

```
grp= df.groupby(by = "col3").groups
grp

{1: Int64Index([0, 2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([5], dtype='int64'),
 10: Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')}
```

you can extract values of 'col', 'col2' that correspond to these indices as such

```
grp_idx= df.groupby(by = "col3").groups
res = {key:df.loc[val,['col1','col2']].values for key,val in grp_idx.items()}
res

{1: array([['a', 'b'],
        ['g', 's'],
        ['y', 'p']], dtype=object),
 2: array([['n', 'c']], dtype=object),
 10: array([['x', 'f'],
        ['q', 't']], dtype=object)}
```

depending on the exact requirements you can further transform the values of `res` to what you need

Answer (score 2):

The class `PrettyDict` [source codes](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/67c9385787c4d854b75a6f2c04fdf6886fdb1a06/pandas/io/formats/printing.py#L548-L552) as follows:

```py
class PrettyDict(Dict[_KT, _VT]):
    """Dict extension to support abbreviated __repr__"""

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return pprint_thing(self)
```

Actually, as we can see that `groups` is a **normal dictionary**.

```py
grp = df.groupby(["col3"])
groups = grp.groups
```

Comment: As Zero said, the PrettyDict inherits from the Python's "dict" class. You can check it with isinstance(groups dict). Thus, you can use it as a normal dictionary.